# IIS - Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the content length exceeds the configured value

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, iis-10

(For starters, I have found a lot of info here on SO, and have followed a lot of the information to no avail.)

I am getting the following error when I upload multiple files to the server.

> HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found The request filtering module is
>   configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.
>
> Most likely causes: Request filtering is configured on the Web server
>   to deny the request because the content length exceeds the configured
>   value.
>
> Things you can try: Verify the
>   configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits@maxAllowedContentLength
>   setting in the applicationhost.config or web.config file.

web.config (In all WebCore servers)

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" maxRequestLength="1048576" shutdownTimeout="90" />
 <security>
   <requestFiltering>
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
   </requestFiltering>
 </security>
```

In the ARR and Web Servers ApplicationHost.config

```
<security>
   <requestFiltering>
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength ="1073741824" />
   </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

I found an [article on this issue](https://www.salamandersoft.co.uk/blog/iis7-the-request-filtering-module-is-configured-to-deny-a-request-that-exceeds-the-request-content-length/), and I tried what was mentioned which is this.

```
appcmd.exe unlock config -section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering
```

I then found this and applied it to all the servers as well.

```
appcmd set config -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:1000000
```

Restarted IIS

```
net stop wmsvc  
net start wmsvc
```

But still, the same error.

I am uploading MP3 files.
If I do 1 to 4, it is fine.
But anything from 5 and up, it gives the error.
The files are less than 5mb in size each.
So it is NOT coming anywhere close to the size limit.

---

Does anyone have any advice they can share with me on this issue?
I have done and tried everything I could find online and nothing works.
I've had this running flawlessly before, I'm talking a few months ago before we lost everything and had to rebuild the Server Farm from scratch again.
And since then, different things have stopped working that used to work.
Components that use to work on the old 2016 DC (The DC was about 3 yrs old)
With the new 2016 DC, stuff has just not been working properly.
I don't THINK the DC would have anything to do with this issue here, at least, I don't think it would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FIXED IT!!!!!!!!!!
From [knowledge.broadcom.com - How to increase Document upload size limit](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/155310/how-to-increase-document-upload-size-lim.html#:~:text=Cause%3A,which%20is%20approximately%2028.6%20MB.)
I did the following

First, I did the below on all the Webservers, But still the same error.
Then I did the same to the ARR server, as it is the entry and WA-LA. Works.

> 1. Install Request Filtering role to your Web Server IIS.
> 2. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
> 3. In the Connections, pane click on Default Web Site.
> 4. In the Home pane, double-click Request Filtering.
> 5. Click Edit Feature Settings... in the Actions pane.
> 6. Increase Maximum allowed content length (Bytes) Click Ok. The default value is 30000000, which is approximately 28.6MB.
> 7. In the Connections, pane click on ProcessManager application and verify that settings are the same as in Default Web Site (steps 5-7).
> 8. It is recommended to Restart IIS.

Default was set at 1000000 = 1mb
So I changed it to 1000000000 = 1000mb

I was SO happy when I did not see that blasted error page.
What I did was the following.
Did a Google Search for: iis 10 file upload size limit
The TOP first listing was the link and information I provided above.
I just tested it and upload 10 files, totalling 75mb, and it uploaded them all.

I can go to bed happy now.
Hope this helps others having the same issue.